# SQL left join not returning all values from left

Tags: sql, left-join

I've tried doing the below SQL query but I can't seem to bring through all the values from the left table. It seems to  ingnore them if there's a match in the right

```
SELECT B.ITMREF_0, B.CPNITMREF_0, B.BOMSEQ_0,
       B1.CPNITMREF_0, B1.BOMSEQ_0, B.YREF_0, B1.YREF_0 
FROM [BOMD] as B
    LEFT JOIN [BOMD] as B1
        on B.CPNITMREF_0=B1.ITMREF_0 AND B.BOMALT_0=B1.BOMALT_0
WHERE B.ITMREF_0='50' 
    and B.BOMALT_0='1'
```

The Item has to be specific and the BOMALT has to be 1.
I've tried adding the WHERE statement into the ON but this doesn't filter correctly.
Any ideas?
Thank you

Edit: thank you for the replies:
Example data: Sorry I have to change the data to show you

BOMD TABLE

```
ITMREF_0  CPNITMREF_0  BOMSEQ_0 BOMALT_0 YREF_0
50        120-001      1        1        F1
50        112-001      2        1        F2
50        110-001      3        1        F3
112-001   113-001      1        1        P2
112-001   113-001      2        1        P3
50        120-001      1        2        D1
50        112-001      2        2        D2
50        110-001      3        2        D3
112-001   113-001      1        2        Q2
112-001   113-001      2        2        Q3
```

Desired Result

```
ITMREF_0  CPNITMREF_0  BOMSEQ_0  CPNITREF_0     BOMSEQ_0 YREF_0 YREF_0
50        120-001      1         NULL           NULL     F1     NULL
50        112-001      2         NULL           NULL     F2     NULL
50        112-001      2         113-001        1        NULL   P2
50        112-001      2         113-001        2        NULL   P3
50        110-001      3         NULL           NULL     F3     NULL
```

Comment: Your query is properly stated.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Wait... why do you expect 50-112-001 with the NULL CPNITREF_0 in your results... Two matchs were found on the join; thus you shouldn't have a Null record value.  And why is YREF_0 Null from B?  Shouldn't it be F2 on the 3,4 records above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why you would get those desired results using your query.

Specifically (line 2 in your results)

```
ITMREF_0  CPNITMREF_0  BOMSEQ_0  CPNITREF_0     BOMSEQ_0 YREF_0 YREF_0
50        112-001      2         NULL           NULL     F2     NULL
```

and the null values in Yref_0 when matching to B1. (lines 3/4 in your results)
Shouldn't they be 'F2' as well?

***Fundamental issue:***  when using outer join you can not have a match and it act like no match record in the same set without some sort a union.  1 rec in B 2 in B1 gives you 2 records... Not 3.    1*2 = 2 to get 3 we have to union in the missing record...

I suspect this is what you're getting now:
[image]

To get what you want I think you'd need to union in the record you want and use some special case logic to display yref_0 the way you want.  The reason why the 2nd record isn't in your results is because it's found on the left join so the null values for CPNitemRef_0 record will not exist.

- make left join an inner ( we only want the matches) (2 records)
- union in the records from your base set so you get all of them (including the 112-001 that had a match  (3 records)
- use a case statement to control the null values on YREF from b the way you want.

[Working DEMO:](http://rextester.com/DRTOH69146)

```
SELECT B.ITMREF_0, B.CPNITMREF_0, B.BOMSEQ_0 BOMSEQ,
       B1.CPNITMREF_0, B1.BOMSEQ_0, case when B1.ITMREF_0 is null then B.YREF_0 else null end as itemRef_0, B1.YREF_0 
FROM BOMD  B
INNER JOIN BOMD B1
  on B.CPNITMREF_0=B1.ITMREF_0 
 AND B.BOMALT_0=B1.BOMALT_0
WHERE B.ITMREF_0='50' 
  and B.BOMALT_0= 1
UNION 
SELECT B.ITMREF_0, B.CPNITMREF_0, B.BOMSEQ_0,
       NULL, NULL, B.YREF_0, NULL
FROM BOMD B
WHERE B.ITMREF_0='50' 
  and B.BOMALT_0= 1;
```

Giving us:

[image]

May need to add `ORDER BY BOMSEQ, BOMSEQ_0;` if order matters.

Comment: Thanks, then union worked a treat with order by BOMSEQs.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.  First question:  Do you understand that "left table" means the "first table"?  I know I can confuse "left" and "right", so I just want to be sure.

You query should be returning exactly the same rows from `BOMD` that this does:

```
SELECT B.*
FROM BOMD B
WHERE B.ITMREF_0 = '50' AND B.BOMALT_0 = '1';
```

Some rows might be duplicated in your query due to multiple matches.  But none of these rows should be filtered out.

Also, don't use single quotes around numeric constants.  If the columns are numbers -- then remove the single quotes.

Comment: I think the issue is the 2nd record in the expected results wouldn't exist due to the left join finding matching records.  So either the expected result is wrong; or the query needs to union that record back in. and some case logic to handle the null values for YREF_0 when a matching record is found on the join.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this part is correct?:

```
B.CPNITMREF_0=B1.ITMREF_0
```

Because then you go on to specify in the where clause:

```
B.ITMREF_0='50'
```

It just seems odd that you would want to join on the left table column A equal to the right table column B, and then specify that left table's column B should be something specific.  It's obviously valid SQL, but without seeing or understanding the actual data it's difficult to say.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. Yes, I need to check the table again encase the part has it's own Bill of Materials in the same table and included it under the part.